# How to show that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $|C|\le c^n?$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, analysis

Give lattice graph $G(\mathbb{Z}^2)=(V(\mathbb{Z}^2), E(\mathbb{Z}^2))$ and a connected set $C$ with $n$ vertices containing the original point $(0,0)$, how to show that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$|C|\le c^n?$$
Here $|C|$ is the number of such connected sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was first bounded by Murray Eden in the paper [A two-dimensional growth process](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1078.9228&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I will give a simplified version of the proof that gives a bound of $2^{4n} = 16^n$, but just by analyzing it more carefully, Eden gets $\binom{3n-2}{n-1}$, and since then the bound has been improved further. (A highly related quantity is the [number of polynominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino#Asymptotic_growth_of_the_number_of_polyominoes) of size $n$.)

The argument is that we'll represent all connected $n$-vertex sets containing $(0,0)$ by distinct sequences of $4n$ bits. The algorithm for doing it is this:

1. Begin with the vertex $(0,0)$ on a stack; mark it as explored.
2. Pop the top vertex $v$ off the stack. Write down a $4$-bit sequence $(n,s,e,w)$ where each bit corresponds to one of the four cardinal directions from $v$, and it is $1$ if there is another vertex from $C$ adjacent to $v$ in that direction.
3. For each unexplored vertex $w \in C$ adjacent to $v$, going in the same N,S,E,W order, put $w$ on the stack and mark it as explored.

For concreteness, I've used a stack, making this depth-first search, but a queue or really any consistent method would work equally well.

After we've explored all $n$ vertices, we get a $4n$-bit sequence, and we can recover $C$ from the sequence. By the time we get to the $i^{\text{th}}$ $4$-bit block, we know where the $i^{\text{th}}$ vertex we processed is; the $4$-bit block lets us deduce which vertices were added to the stack at that time, and accordingly where they are.

To improve the bound of $2^{4n}$ to something smaller, we argue that:

1. We can skip many of the bits, because we knew they were there. Each vertex $v$ after the first has a "parent" $u$ that was the first to explore $v$. We can skip the $1$ bit in $v$'s sequence that corresponds to the direction $u$ is from $v$, because we already know $u$ is there. This leaves us with only $3n+1$ bits.
2. We can also skip the other three bits on the last vertex, since they'll be $0$, leaving us with $3n-2$.
3. We can write down $1$ only if there's an *unexplored* vertex in a direction, and $0$ otherwise. Now there are only $n-1$ bits that are $1$, so there's $\binom{3n-2}{n-1}$ sequences. These still encode all possible sets $C$.

Comment: What a professional answer! I am sorry for my silly mistake. Dear professor, I am curious whether considering the spaning tree of $C$ is feasible or not?

Comment: We are essentially doing exactly that. But you want a *specific* spanning tree to have a "canonical" encoding: here, we take the DFS tree, but the exact choice is unimportant.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems that Eden gets upper bound $\frac{1}{4n}\binom{3n-2}{n-1}$?

Comment: @Hermi That's because Eden is counting polyominoes, so for him, we should divide by the possible orientations, and the possible starting points. We are not counting polyominoes: for us, the set $\{(0,0), (0,1)\}$ and the set $\{(0,-1), (0,0)\}$ are different.